# Typing too fast, strange hidden characters

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, internationalization

I have this annoying problem since long. I use to type quite fast, and it happens to me that after inserting a special character using the "alt" key I probably do not wait enough to press the space bar. I don't see the difference then, but then when the command is interpreted in the terminal, or the script I just wrote is executed, lots of errors come up because there are hidden strange characters (gremlins). Is there any way I can avoid this?

Comment: Type slower (or train yourself to release Opt/Alt faster)...

Comment: It inserts a non-breaking space. This is a fairly common problem. [This question](http://superuser.com/q/78245/100252) has plenty of good answers. Some a application specific and some global.

Comment: Thank you very much Joonas! I am so happy I sorted this out. For the terminal the basic trick worked. For TextWrangler I had to use BetterTouchTool.

Answer (score 1):

Your option + space combination defaults to a non-breaking space and several options to remove that binding exist.

- https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces

Whether you choose to show invisible characters in your  editor to manually proof for these issues or use a lint type tool or change the behavior of the system depends on whether you can avoid typing that combination after knowing it exists.